# Why does looping over a large amount of data in another thread cause an overactive GC, and prevent some data from being freed?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure, garbage-collection

I'm writing code that takes some lazy results produced by `pmap`, and draws them onto a `BufferedImage`. For three days now I've been trying to figure out why the drawing suddenly starts freezing and eventually halts about a 1/3 of the way through.

I've finally narrowed it down to the fact that I'm looping over a large amount of data in another thread.

This is the best MCVE that I've come up with:

```
(ns mandelbrot-redo.irrelevant.write-image-mcve
  (:import [java.awt.image BufferedImage]
           (java.util.concurrent Executors Executor)))

(defn lazy-producer [width height]
  (for [y (range height)
        x (range width)]
    [x y (+ x y)]))

; This works fine; finishing after about 5 seconds when width=5000
(defn sync-consumer [results width height]
  (time
    (doseq [[i result] (map vector (range) results)]
      (when (zero? (rem i 1e6))
        (println (str (double (/ i (* width height) 0.01)) "%")))

      ((fn boop [x] x) result)))) ; Data gets consumed here

; This gets to ~30%, then begins being interupted by 1-4 second lags
(defn async-consumer [results width height]
  (doto
    (Thread. ^Runnable
             (fn []
               (sync-consumer results width height)
               (println "Done...")))
    (.start)))

(defn -main []
  (let [width 5000
        height (int (* width 2/3))]
    (-> (lazy-producer width height)
        (async-consumer width height))))
```

When `-main` is run with `sync-consumer`, it finishes after a few seconds. With `async-consumer` however, it gets to about 25%, then begins slowing to a crawl to the point where the last printed percentage is 30%. If I leave it, I get an OOME.

If I use an explicit `Thread.`, or use a local thread pool in `async-consumer`, it hangs and crashes. If I use `future` however, it finishes fine, just like `sync-consumer`.

The only hint I've gotten is that when I run this in VisualVM, I see that I have runaway allocation of `Long`s when using the async version:

[image: VisualVM Snapshot]

The sync version shows a peak amount of `Long`s to be about 45mb at once in comparison.

The CPU usage is quite different too:

[image]

There's massive GC spikes, but it doesn't seem like the `Long`s are being disposed of.

I *could* use `future` for this, but I've been bitten by its exception swallowing behavior so many times, I'm hesitant.

Why is this happening? Why is running this in a new thread causing the GC to go crazy, while at the same time numbers aren't being freed?

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sync version seems to be processing through the 16M+ results and will not hold onto the head of the results seq due to locals clearing. This means that as you go, values are created, processed, and GC'ed.

The async one closes over `results` in the fn and will hold the head, keeping all 16M+ values in memory, likely leading to GC thrashing?

I actually can't reproduce what you describe - both sync and async take about the same time for me as written above. (Clojure 1.9, Java 1.8).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. The use of a function seems necessary to running this in an another thread though, *and* `future` works consistently while manually created thread pools don't.

Comment: This looks 100% correct to me. @Carcigenicate You can test this hypothesis by replacing the `(fn ...)` in `async-consumer` with `(^:once fn* ...)`. This promises to the compiler that you will only call the function once, so it realizes that locals-clearing of its closure is safe.

Comment: @amalloy Oh! I did not know about that. I'm praying that fixes it. Thank you!

Comment: @amalloy That explains a lot actually. [`future` does exactly what you describe](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6917) , which would explain why it works while nothing else does. I have to pack now, but I suspect I'll be accepting this. The `^once` metadata idea should be added to this answer.

Comment: `^:once` is kinda a compiler internal that is not guaranteed to exist. It's not really what you should be using in production. It'd be better to not create a new Thread, in this simple example. I imagine in real life you can't help it because you're using some threadpool. In that case, consider replacing `(fn [] (whatever local))` with `(let [p (delay (whatever local))] (fn [] @p))`. The compiler knows the function backing a `delay` will only be called once.

Comment: @amalloy Oh, ok. And thanks, I'll play around with that idea later.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified you example, and get inconsistent results.  I suspect that the manual `Thread` object is somehow being regarded (sometimes) as a daemon thread, so the JVM sometimes exits before it has completed:

```
(def N 5e3)
(def total-count (* N N))
(def report-fact (int (/ total-count 20)))

(defn lazy-producer []
  (for [y (range N)
        x (range N)]
    [x y (+ x y)]))

(defn sync-consumer [results]
  (println "sync-consumer:  start")
  (time
    (doseq [[i result] (map vector (range) results)]
      (when (zero? (rem i report-fact))
        (println (str (Math/round (/ (* 100 i) total-count)) " %")))))
  (println "sync-consumer:  stop"))

 (defn async-consumer [results]
  ; (spyx (count results))
  (spyx (nth results 99))
  (let [thread (Thread. (fn []
                          (println "thread  start")
                          (sync-consumer results)
                          (println "thread  done")
                          (flush)))]
    ; (.setDaemon thread false)
    (.start thread)
    (println "daemon?   " (.isDaemon thread))
    thread))

(dotest
  (println "test - start")
  (let [thread (async-consumer
                 (lazy-producer))]
    (when true
      (println "test - sleeping")
      (Thread/sleep 5000))
 ;  (.join thread)
  )
  (println "test - end"))
```

with results:

```
----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0    Java 10.0.1
----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core
test - start
(nth results 99) => [99 0 99]
daemon?    false
test - sleeping
thread  start
sync-consumer:  start
0 %
5 %
10 %
15 %
20 %
25 %
30 %
35 %
40 %
45 %
50 %
55 %
test - end

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
60 %
lein test  54.58s user 1.37s system 372% cpu 15.028 total
```

If we uncomment the `(.join thread)` line, we get a complete run:

```
~/expr/demo > lein test

----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0    Java 10.0.1
----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core
test - start
(nth results 99) => [99 0 99]
daemon?    false
test - sleeping
thread  start
sync-consumer:  start
0 %
5 %
10 %
15 %
20 %
25 %
30 %
35 %
40 %
45 %
50 %
55 %
60 %
65 %
70 %
75 %
80 %
85 %
90 %
95 %
"Elapsed time: 9388.313828 msecs"
sync-consumer:  stop
thread  done
test - end

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
lein test  72.52s user 1.69s system 374% cpu 19.823 total
```

It seems to exit early as if Clojure killed off the manual `Thread` object.

Perhaps you have found an (intermittent) bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this tomorrow; it's been a long day. How would the JVM exiting cause the observed behavior though? And most of my testing was done in a REPL, so I don't think the JVM is exiting, or that would be reflected in the REPL. I updated my question too to note that this is occurring using while using manual thread pools too (cached and fixed), but *not* when using `future`. The Agent's pool is the only context where its working for some reason. The only differences I can see between it and a manually created one are the use of a factory, and that I'm also using the same

Comment: Pool elsewhere via `pmap`. Maybe I should create my own pool and try running some stuff on it prior? Idk. This has done me in for the day.

Comment: Your test code is what contains the bug. You start a thread in the middle of a test, and then don't wait for it to complete, so as far as lein knows, your tests are all done, and the JVM is ready to terminate. The default lein behavior is to call System/exit after your tests complete. This is a bug not present in the code in the question.

Comment: I suspected System/exit might be the cause. I didn't realize the behavior was different for `lein test` than `lein run` with regard to non-daemon threads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @amalloy and @Alex, I got it working.

I implemented the suggestions by @amalloy in the comments, and both variants work here and in my real case:

```
; Brittle since "once" is apparently more of an implementation detail of the language
(defn async-consumer [results width height]
  (doto
    (Thread. ^Runnable
             (^:once fn* []
               (sync-consumer results width height)
               (println "Done...")))
    (.start)))

; Arguably less brittle under the assumption that if they replace "once" with another mechanism,
;  they'll update "delay".
(defn async-consumer [results width height]
  (let [d (delay (sync-consumer results width height))]
    (doto
      (Thread. ^Runnable
               (fn []
                 @d
                 (println "Done...")))
      (.start))))
```

I also tried updating to 1.9.0. I thought that might fix it since @Alex says he's on 1.9.0 and can't reproduce this, and [there's also this bug fix that seems related.](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1744) Unfortunately, I didn't notice any difference.

It would be nice if there was an actual, solid mechanism for this. `^:once` seems fine, but I don't want to use if just to have it potentially break later, and the use of `delay` seems like blatant abuse of the object just to make use of its inner `(^:once fn* ...)`.

Oh well, at least it works now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Ha! I was able to apply this to another similar situation and plug a (small) leak that I wasn't even aware of.